# VB.NET Table Adapter not inserting row in the database

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert

I wrote this really simple query in the dataset designer:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (Id, Nome)
VALUES (@Id, @Nome);  

SELECT Id, Nome 
FROM tabela 
WHERE (Id = @Id)
```

When I run this in the query builder, it inserts the data into the SQL database normally.

My problem is: I created a button on the form, and added this code to the button click event handler:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim Nome As String

    ID = 1
    Nome = "teste"

    TabelaTableAdapter.NovoItem(ID, Nome)
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I click in the button, nothing happens in my database, no row is inserted.

Where is the issue?

Comment: the problem is likely in `NovoItem`

Comment: What value is returned by that call to the `NovoItem` method?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get exactly your questions or comments. NovoItem is a query that is receiving 2 parameters such as ID and Nome. When I run this command using form button, nothing happens. The row is not inserted in my database.

Comment: where is `TabelaTableAdapter.NovoItem` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue. I found this comment in the internet that fixed my problem:

> his issue can be fixed by clicking on the database in the solution explorer and adjusting the property to read 'Copy if Newer' instead of 'Copy Always'.  If you set it to 'Do Not Copy', you need to manually copy it or you an exception saying that it can't find the database file.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67b68979-bf82-4bfc-bb53-0955b6ddaeec/tableadapterupdate-does-not-save-data?forum=Vsexpressinstall)